# Modify Listbox entries via listvariable in Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I read in a tutorial that I can separate the data from the `tkinter.Listbox` into my own list. I did this in the example here.
But how can I manipulate the order of the Listbox-entries based on my own variablelist?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
mylist = ['one', 'two', 'three']
var = StringVar(value=mylist)
box = Listbox(master=root, listvariable=var)
box.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# this need to affect the list
mylist.append('four')
mylist.remove('two')
mylist.insert(3, mylist.pop(1))

root.mainloop()
```

The Listbox (in the GUI) here is not affected.

As I understand there is a way that `Listbox` refresh absolut automaticly its content when I modify the data-list. So I don't have to touch `Listbox`. I only need to touch the data in the `list()`.

Is there a way?

Comment: you can remove all items from `box` and add new items from `mylist`. [Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) on effbot.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Listbox](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm) has `get()`, `delete()` and `insert()`.
You can get value from `box`, remove it and put it in new place.

Or you can remove all items from `box` and add new items from `mylist`.
I think this method is more universal.

```
box.delete(0, 'end')
for item in mylist:
    box.insert('end', item)
```

Because you use `listvariable` so you can replace list directly in `var`

```
var.set(mylist)
```

Full code

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

mylist = ['one', 'two', 'three']

var = StringVar(value=mylist)
box = Listbox(master=root, listvariable=var)
box.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

mylist.append('four')
mylist.remove('two')
mylist.insert(3, mylist.pop(1))

var.set(mylist)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ah I see. The mechanism is not 100% automatic. Thanks.